# Why can't I create a new node in linked list without pointers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand linked lists. I have this code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node_t;
 
void printlist(node_t *head){
    //temp is just a pointer to a node; not actually a node
    node_t *temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("%d ", temp->value);
    while (temp != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
         
    }
}
 
node_t create_new_node(int value){
    node_t node;
    node.value = value;
    node.next = NULL;
    return node;        
}
 
int main(){
    node_t *head;
    node_t tmp;
     
    tmp = create_new_node(32);
    head = &tmp;
     
    tmp = create_new_node(87);
    tmp.next = head;
    head = &tmp;
    
    printlist(head);
     
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program, nothing shows. My question is, why doesn't create_new_node work here? Wouldn't node be statically allocated? I know pointers would make it work, I just want to see why this doesn't. I tried using malloc here, it didn't work, probably because it's not assigned to a pointer.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the program shows nothing? I just compiled and ran it, ending up an indefinite loop with printing `87`.

Comment: Why do you think main() would give you a pristine 2nd 'tmp' to fill with different data?

Comment: You only have **one** `node_t (i.e. `tmp`) that you overwrite by the second `create_new_node` call. Then you set the `next` pointer to point to itself. So you have created a circular list with **one** element... Consequently, `printlist` will be an endless loop.

Comment: Here is your code with one change. Instead of calling `printlist` it prints the pointer values. They are all the same, i.e. the list is circular. https://ideone.com/w7cvdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style notes: modern C has compound literals, and you do not need to separately declare and initialize, so let's just write:

```
node_t temp = (node_t){.value=32, .next=NULL};
```

Rewriting your code to cut out the excess and streamline `printlist`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    int value;
    node_t *next;
};
 
void printlist(node_t *head) {
    //temp is just a pointer to a node; not actually a node
    node_t *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->value); 
        temp = temp->next;  
    }
}
 
int main() {
    node_t tmp = (node_t){ .value=32, .next=NULL };
    node_t *head = &tmp;

    printlist(head);
     
    tmp = (node_t){ .value=87, .next=NULL };
    tmp.next = head;
    head = &tmp;
    
    printlist(head);
     
    return 0;
}
```

The fact that `tmp` is not a pointer means that it represents memory space for exactly one node. You end up with exactly one node that circularly points to itself.

Your `create_new_node` function should dynamically allocate a new node.

```
node_t *create_new_node(int value) {
    node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (!result) return NULL;
    result->value = value;
    result->next = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in your function there is no creation of new node taking place just the previously existing node is  being assigned the values while to add new node add  this....and pass the address of node to which you want to add next node as parameter

```
//take funtion as void becasue no need to return anythning
 void create_new_node(node_t* node){
 //create a new node and pointing the pointer of base to the new node
 node.next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

 /*there is no need to return any value just simple assign to it as it will 
  decrease time complexity.Like instead of creating and then assgning next 
 and then return just simply assign to reduce time complextity*/
 }
```

Add the constructor to your defination of struct node that will assign the value NULL on everytime creation to your next pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your `main()` function.

```c
int main() {
  node_t *head;
  node_t tmp;
  tmp = create_new_node(32);
  head = &tmp;
  tmp = create_new_node(87);
  printf("%d\n", head->value);  // 32 or 87?
  return 0;
}
```

Should it print `32` or `87`?

If you can understand that it actually prints `87`, instead of `32`, then everything will become clear.

Let's look at the code line by line.

1. `node_t tmp;`

There is some stack memory allocated to store a `node_t` object.

Let's say a `node_t` object takes up 16 bytes, so `tmp` now occupies an area of memory whose address is

```
0x100, 0x101, 0x102, ..., 0x10f
```

2. `tmp = create_new_node(32);`

A `node_t` with value `32` now is stored in the above area of memory, from `0x100` to `0x10f`.

3. `head = &tmp;`

`head` now stores the address of `tmp`, which is `0x100`.

4. `tmp = create_new_node(87);`

The **exactly same** memory area, starting with `0x100`, now stores a node with value `87`.

The old node with value `32` is gone at this moment.

5. `printf("%d\n", head->value);`

Print out the value of the node where `head` points, i.e. at `0x100`, which is `87`.

---

It is desirable to need to understand

```c
tmp = create_new_node(value);
```

The right-hand side returns a `node_t` (a struct, which could be large, not a pointer), and puts it in the memory occupied by the `tmp` in the left-hand side. So this assignment is storing the real value, not the address.

---

By the way, there is one more problem in your program.

```c
while (temp != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    printf("%d ", temp->value);
}
```

You should check the next node is not null, instead of checking the node itself, before moving on to the next one.